# Javascript: Arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason my values are not being stored in the array:

```
var req = new Array();
$.get('./ajax/get_cat_info.php?cid=' +cid, function(data, textStatus) {
    var count = 0;
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        $('#' + key).show();
        if(val == 1) {
            req[count] = key;
            count = count + 1;
            //var arLen=req.length;
            //alert('l: ' + arLen); // this works though
        }
    });
}, 'json');

var arLen=req.length;
alert('l: ' + arLen);
```

I get alerted "l: 0" at the end. If I uncomment the line alert in the IF statement, it alerts on each one, then still alerts 0.

Comment: try `req.push(key)` instead of `req[count] = key;`?

Comment: The code below the `$.get` statement executes immediately, ergo, **before** the callback function because the callback is asynchronous. Your array is OK, but you can't use it before the callback has finished. Btw, this is a common mistake.

Comment: if you moved your alert up into the callback after the each, it would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `get` call is running asynchronously, and so `arLen=req.length` is being evaluated prior to the function of elements being set actually completing. You can set the values accordingly from within the callback of the async call, as you determined.

Comment: I'm searching for examples, but can't seem to find much. Should I still use .get or switch to .ajax?

Answer (score 7):

AJAX requests are, by default, asynchronous. You'll either have to change the AJAX request to be synchronous, or use the value of `req` in the callback.

In addition, you might want to use `req.push(key)` rather than using a `count` variable and `req[count] = key;` (although this isn't your problem).